Where Can I Find Sample or Synthetic Patient Data Records in PDF Format for Extraction Projects?
I'm currently working on a project that involves extracting information from patient data records, specifically in a format that would typically be received through a Subject Access Request (SAR). I'm looking for a sample, anonymised, or synthetic patient data record in PDF format. Ideally, this would include comprehensive patient information such as:

Vitals, Clinical notes, Medical history, Letters and correspondence,
Other relevant patient documentation

So far, I've only been able to find datasets in CSV format, which isn't suitable for my extraction project since I need data in the same format that real-world documents are exported in, i.e., PDF.
Does anyone know where can I find such sample data in PDF format? It needs to be either anonymised real data, synthetic data, or some kind of publicly available mock-up that I can use legally for development purposes. Any leads on where to find this kind of resource would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Context:
The goal is to use this data to test and improve a document extraction tool that is meant to process real patient records. The tool needs to handle the variability and complexity found in real-world PDF documents, including variations in formatting and content structure. Free or open-access sources would be ideal, but I'm open to any suggestions, including those requiring a license or permission to use.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Does "HL7 FHIR" and "C-CDA" format will work for you?
